# How to Alphabetize a CSS file in Vim

Tags: vim

I get a CSS file:

```
div#header h1 {
    z-index: 101;
    color: #000;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin-right: 48px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
    font-size: 18px;
}

div#header h2 {
    z-index: 101;
    color: #000;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin-right: 48px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

I want to **Alphabetize** lines between the **{...}**

```
div#header h1 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin-right: 48px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 101;
}

div#header h2 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin-right: 48px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 101;
}
```

I map <kbd>F7</kbd> to do it

```
nmap <F7> /{/+1<CR>vi{:sort<CR>
```

But I need to press <kbd>F7</kbd> over and over again to get the work done.
If the CSS file is big, It's time-consuming & easily get bored.
I want to get the cmds piped. So that, I only press <kbd>F7</kbd> once!
Any idea? thanks!

Comment: How is this exactly off topic, closer?

Comment: it's really neat that this is possible, but this has to potential to cause many new CSS-related bugs with attributes that have been defined in a specific order

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
:g#\({\n\)\@<=#.,/}/sort
```

Explanation:

```
g        " Work over the whole file running .,/}/sort on each line that matches
         " the pattern \({\n\)\@<=
#...#... " Delimiters: first bit is search pattern, second bit is what
         " to do on each matching line
\(       " Grouping, containing:
  {\n    " Open brace followed by new line
\)       " End of grouping
\@<=     " Negative look-behind, so match after the new-line, but make sure that
         " the match point is preceded by an open brace and a new-line

.,/}/    " From this line to the next closing brace...
sort     " Sort the lines
```

You can of course map this to a keyboard shortcut or make it into a command:

```
:nmap <F7> :g#\({\n\)\@<=#.,/}/sort<CR>

" Or:

:command! SortCSSBraceContents :g#\({\n\)\@<=#.,/}/sort
```

Then you can simply hit <kbd>F7</kbd> or run:

```
:SortCSSBraceContents
```

Comment: The only catch is that if I run this in a say, an HTML file with CSS and Javascript, it also tries to sort all of my JS Objects.

Comment: Any ideas on how you would get this to sort -webkit- and -moz- values to appear near, but always before their cross-browser counterparts? I'm using the "sort {pattern}" feature to ignore the -*- stuff when sorting,  but doesn't then order the -moz/-webkit/(real) like I would prefer: 

  sort/\s*\(-\a*-\\|\)/

Answer (score 7):

```
nnoremap <S-F7> zRgg:while search("{$", 'W') \| .+1,/}$/-1sort \| endwhile<CR>
```

This is what it does:

1. `zR` opens all folds.
2. `gg` moves the cursor to the first line.
3. `search("{$")` searches for the opening brace at the end of line and moves cursor to the found position.
4. `search(, 'W')` prevents `search()` from wrapping over the end of file, so it will return false after last found position.
5. `.+1,/}$/-1` sets the range to «from one line after (`+1`) cursor position (`.`) to the line before (`-1`) the closing brace at the end of line (`/}$/`)».
6. `sort` sorts, you know it.

Answer (score 1):

For SCSS stylesheets:

`:g#\({\n\)\@<=#.,/\.*[{}]\@=/-1 sort`

This looks for either a closing curly brace or another open curly brace and selects the line before it.

Answer (score 0):

For Vuejs single file components, inline style, etc - where you need the command to run only within  element:

```
:/<style>/,/<\/style>/:g#\({\n\)\@<=#.,/}/sort
```