# How to make vim alphabetically sort CSS rules within a single line?

Tags: css, sorting, vim

Source:

```
.foo { line-height: 150px; font-size: 24px; clear: both; }
```

*vim magic here, probably something visual selection based*

Result:

```
.foo { clear: both; font-size: 24px; line-height: 150px; }
```

What do you suggest for the vim magic part?

Comment: Good stuff everyone, this is why I love SO. Side note: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050797/how-to-alphabetize-a-css-file-in-vim seems to be related for multi-line CSS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
:s/\([{;]\)\s*/\1\r/g | '[+1,']sort | '[,']join
```

Split the line on `{` or `;` to get each rule into a separate line, `:sort` them (omitting the first line containing the CSS definition), then join them back together.

Comment: Better than mine on every count.

Comment: You can make this a tiny bit shorter by using `s/[{;]/&\r` for your substitute.  The whitespace gets stripped eventually anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Very quick answer:

```
:s/[{;] /\0\r
vi{
:!sort
va{
J
```

Comment: This is how I learned that 'J' can operate on a selection.  Neat!

Answer (score 1):

Another one-liner:

```
s/{\s*\zs.\{-}\ze\s*}/\=join(sort(split(submatch(0), '\s*;\s*')), '; ').';'
```

This time we use `sub-replace-\=`, and list manipulation functions (`sort()`, `split()`, and `join()`)