# How to divide on column data to multiple columns

Tags: vim, multiple-columns, vi

I have the following data block as a sample:

```
0.1 A
0.2 B
0.3 C

0.1 E
0.2 F
0.3 G
...
```

which I want to divide them to multiple lines when a new line appears

```
0.1 A E H ...

0.2 B F I ...

0.3 C G J ...
```

I can use the column editing mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) in the vim to manually paste the data to a new column for simple case, but when the new line `/r` segments become hundreds, that is impossible.
Is there a way to let vim move the following data to a new column every time it saw a empty line?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways that what you need could be done, but here is one that I came up with.

```
for i in range(1, 3)
    exe '4,$g/\v0\.' . i . '/exe "normal! ^dWd\<Space>4G?0.' . i . '\<CR>A\<Space>\<Esc>p"'
endfor
```

This only works on the specific case that you gave me, but I will show you how to adapt it to your needs. Here is a breakdown of the command in the middle of the for loop:

```
exe '4,$g/\v0\.' . i .
 ^      ^          ^
 |      |          |
 |      |          |
 |      |  Part of the for loop, in this case it searches for 0.x
 |      |
 |  Takes in a command line range,
 |  (line 4 through end of file)
 |  searches for pattern in between
 |  two slashes, (like :s command)
 |  And executes the following command
 |  on the searched lines.
 |
Runs a vim command from string
```

Now for the command following the `g` command:

```
'/exe "normal! ^dWd\<Space>4G?0.' . i . '\<CR>A\<Space>\<Esc>p"'
```

First, this uses the `exe` command to execute a normal command.  Why this is useful is because special keys like `<Esc>` aren't translated in normal commands.  When used in an `exe` command however, they are translated. This set of keystrokes is performed on every line between line 4 and the end of the file matching `0.x`.  In order, here is what each keystroke in the `normal` command does:

- `^` - Go to beginning of line
- `dW` - Delete a WORD *(in this case, this deletes the 0.x)*
- `d\<Space>` - Deletes a single character, which in this case is the letter after 0.x. *(change this if you want to copy more than just a single character)*
- `4G` - Go to line 4 of the file.  *(Just after the first three rows of data, change this if you have more than three rows at the top)*
- `?0.' . i . '\<CR>` - Search backwards for the according 0.x
- `A\<Space>\<Esc>p` - Append space to end of row, get out of insert, and put deleted char at end of line

Here are some relevant vim help topics if you need more information:

```
:help :g
:help cmdline-ranges
:help :normal
:help :exe
```

Answer (score 1):

Before a vim guru finds a one-liner solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687191/how-to-make-vim-alphabetically-sort-css-rules-within-a-single-line/10688171#10688171), you may want to use the following custom function that performs the joins per index integers :

```
"range function to join lines ordered by a "X" pattern where X is an integer 
"This function is an attempt to answer SO question #28259859 by F14r3
function! F14r3_28259859() range
  let pmatch = ""
  let acc = ""
  let oline = a:lastline + 1
  for linenum in range(a:firstline, a:lastline)
    let curr_line   = getline(linenum)
    let cmatch = matchlist(curr_line,'\(\d\+\) \(.\+\)')
    if (acc=="")
      let acc = curr_line
      let pmatch = cmatch[1]
    else
      if (pmatch==cmatch[1])
        let acc = acc . " " . cmatch[2]
        if (linenum==a:lastline)
          call setline(oline,acc)
        endif
      else
        call setline(oline,acc)
        let pmatch = cmatch[1]
        let acc=curr_line
        let oline = oline + 1
      endif
    endif
  endfor
  return 0
endfunction
```

Here are the steps to use it.

0- Store the function in a buffer and source it (**:so %**)

1- Start with an input file like this :

```
1 Aaaa
2 Bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
3 Cc
1 Ee  ee
2 F
3 G
```

2- Run this Ex-cmd -> **:sort**, and you get :

```
1 Aaaa
1 Ee  ee
2 Bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
2 F
3 Cc
3 G
```

3- Visual Select linewise (**V**) the sorted lines and call (type **:**) the function (after you input F, ask for completion by **tab**) like this :

```
'<,'>call F14r3_28259859()
```

4- Check the result, it should be like this (the joined lines are at the end of the buffer) :

```
1 Aaaa
1 Ee  ee
2 Bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
2 F
3 Cc
3 G
1 Aaaa Ee  ee
2 Bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb F
3 Cc G
```

5- If you are happy with the result, delete sorted lines by **gv** (reselect) and **d**

```
1 Aaaa Ee  ee
2 Bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb F
3 Cc G
```

6- Note that this function contains a regex for simple integers only ; you should modify it to accept your format "0.1" with dots.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that doesn't require a bunch of scripting and uses only simple commands and pattern-based ranges. The following will operate on the whole file but it can be adopted for a range of lines.

First, since it looks like each line has a nice index at the beginning of the line, start by sorting the file:

```
:sort
```

Next, go through each indexed line, and join it to all lines up to the next index (since the file is now sorted, all such lines will be together, and before the next index). For this to work easily, simply append the "next" unused index on a line by itself at the end of the file. In this case, 0.4. And then run the following command:

```
:for i in range(1,3) | exec 'g#0\.'.i.'#.,/0\.'.(i+1).'/-1j' | endfor
```

This will run a `:g` command on lines matching "0.1", "0.2", "0.3" in turn. The command that runs is (for example) `:.,/0.2/-1j` which says "join all lines from this line, until the line before the next match for '0.2'". Thus your file will now look like this:

```
0.1 A 0.1 E 0.1 H
0.2 B 0.2 F 0.2 I
0.3 C 0.3 G 0.3 J
0.4
```

Note that 0.4 I added after sorting, to allow the (i+1) range to match when processing the last set of actual data lines.

Now it's easy to strip out the extra index columns:

```
:%s# 0\.\d\+##g
```

Finally, just delete that extra index we added after sorting.